# Ontology of quantities and Zero quantities

Tags: philosophy-of-science, ontology

How does the ontological status of quantities allow us to discuss the empty value (0) of a given quantity? For example, we may say that there is 'no distance' between two points but may also say that 'the distance is zero' (implying the distance exists).

For every object does every physical quantity exist, allowing us to define an infinite number of quantities of value 0?

Are the quantities themselves the numerical values or are the numerical values, just attributed to allow us to measure them?

Comment: I think most people will read your two sentences and not posit two different ontologies. Just different wordings of, there are two points  and they are overlapping.

Comment: Is zero distance really a special case here? Does a distance of ten exist? Suppose you measure a distance of exactly ten. Improve your measurement accuracy by ten times and it's almost certain that the measurement will change to something like 9.8 or 10.1. Improve your measurement accuracy again, and it will change again. You can never know that you are at exactly 10 units.

Comment: "there is 'no distance" is only a figure of speech. A distance function inputs two points and outputs a nonnegative real number. If the two points are the same, it outputs the number 0.

Comment: "quantities" are what we are used to count with numbers. Thus, a *zero* quantity is perfectly "sound": consider your bank account: it can be positive, negative or zero.